# Identify Closure Memory Leak

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, closures

I'm currently writing a simple api where you post an `array` (length = 200) and since each element in the array needs to do 1-2 look up requests, I'm using the async library to control the flow of things. I'm using node 0.12.5 & Express.

```js
router.post('/data', function(req, res, next) {

    var cloudDB = db.cloudant.use('events');
    var tempStorage = {"docs": []};

    // This each loop is to make sure all events get iterated through before submitting response
    async.each(req.body, function(singleEvent, loopCallback) {

        // this should be async waterfall or something better to organize it
        async.waterfall(
            [
                function(callback) { // get user data from db
                    db.getUserInfo(singleEvent.email, function (error, dbResponse) {
                        if(error) { // Houston, we have a problem
                            return callback(error);
                        }
                        return callback(null, dbResponse);
                    })
                },
                function(dbResponse, callback) { // decide what to do about results
                    if(!dbResponse) {            // we were unable to get the user from DB
                        db.searchForUser(singleEvent.email, function (err, searchResponse) {
                            if(err)
                                return callback(err);
                            else
                                return callback(null, JSON.parse(searchResponse));
                        })
                    }
                    else {
                        return callback(null,JSON.parse(dbResponse));
                    }
                },
                function(userInfo, callback) { // combine data into proper logic
                    callback(null,combineEventAndUserData(singleEvent,userInfo));
                }
            ],
            function (err, result) {
                // User event has been processed, so if there are no errors, lets add it to the queue
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                else {
                    tempStorage.docs.push(result); 
                }
                loopCallback(); // We're done with this singleEvent
            }
        )
    }, function(err) { // function gets called when all singleEvents have been looped through
        console.log("Finished each");
        if(err) {
            res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        else {
            cloudDB.bulk(tempStorage, function(err, body) {
                if(!err) {
                    res.status(200).send(body);
                }
                else {
                    res.status(500).send(err);
                }
            })
        }
    });
});
```

So, this code works! However... (sniff sniff), I seem to have created a memory leak. I have taken a look at both [memwatch-next](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memwatch-next) and [heapdump](https://www.npmjs.com/package/heapdump), and all I've been able to tell was that 'arrays' keep growing when I look at the heap dump.

I don't know why, but I have a suspicion that this might have something to do with closures and how I'm storing the items generated from each of the waterfalls and perhaps the tempStorage.docs is not being released? Am I storing the tempStorage in the correct way? Or should I change how I do that?

Comment: I do not know much about Node, but if you suspect it to have anything to do with `tempStorage` not being released, you could try to manually remove the reference and maybe also try to manually call the garbage collector. See if that makes a difference.

Comment: As long as none of your async operations are getting stuck and never calling their completion callback, I don't see any memory leak here.  This closure only lasts while the async operations that contain references within it are active.  When they are done, the request scope (which contains the `tempStorage` object should be garbage collected.

Comment: @Tim - you don't manually release local variables in Javascript or need to.  And, there's no reason to manually call the garbage collector in Javascript when using asynchronous operations (as there is plenty of time for it to run on its own).  I don't think we have any evidence that the `tempStorage` object is actually the culprit yet.

Comment: @jfriend00 That's true, but you can 'release' the reference: `tempStorage = null;`. And like I said: I don't know much about Node (and the async features).

Comment: You are going to need to delve into exactly which arrays it is that are growing.  Are you sure it isn't built-in caches in your web server framework or your database?

Comment: @Tim - if you have to do that, then something else is broken that really should be found and fixed because that is not necessary in correctly operating code.  Better to find the real cause.  But, I suspect that `tempStorage` isn't even the culprit here anyway.

Comment: @jfriend00 I do not argue about that. I meant: because he was suspecting  it to have anything to do with `tempStorage` not being released, he could try to exclude it by seeing if it makes a difference (or not) by manually removing it from memory. I'm not saying that it's a solution to his problem.

Comment: @Tim - that's a fair test as an investigation only (not an actual solution).

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of trying to remove that variable entirely to see if that solves the problem, good idea @tim. I'll be sure to run manual garbage collection then to see if this even is the problem.

Comment: @Deftness - there is zero reason to manually run garbage collection when using lots of async operations.  That would only be interesting if you had a long running synchronous operation (which you do not).